# Backbone.Marionette - best way to wire up page actions

Tags: marionette

We are using marionette, and we are wiring up actions for elements that live in templates in the $(document).ready() function.  I'm wondering if there is a preferred way to do it - i.e., move it into the model or somewhere inside the Application scope.

Simplified Example

```
<script type="text/template" id="menu">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="index-link">
</script>


MyApp.module("Entities", function (Entities, MyApp, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) {
    Entities.MenuModel = Backbone.Marionette.Model.extend({});
});

MyApp.module("Views", function (Views, QaApp, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) {
    Views.MenuView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
        template: "#menu"
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {

    $(window).load(function() {
      $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 750);
    });

    $(".index-link").on("click", function(e) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/someurl",
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.Status == false)
                    console.warn(result.Message); 
            },
            error: function (result) {
                console.warn(result.Message); 
            }
        });
    });
});
```

In this example, I can see where the window scroll function is unrelated to my model, so it seems ok, but shouldn't the action that is triggered by an element in my template be inside the related view, esp if the success function might return data that my model needs?

Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be aware of the different responsibilities your Marionette/Backbone entities have. The responsibilities generally follow the kind of information that is naturally available to those entities.

In your specific case that means, that DOM events have to be handled by the **views** that contain those DOM elements. Regarding your `$('.index-link')`, you will have to convert into an instance of Marionette.View first. You can do this via Marionette.ItemView/CollectionView/CompositieView or via Marionette.Regions which can themselves be part of Marionette.Layout.

Anyways, your first realization has to be, that this logic has to be handled in the view, not the model. Because only the view knows about the DOM. The model doesn't even know what a DOM is...

**Example**

Seemingly contrary to what I have just told you, I will write "view logic" into the collection. However, consider, that I am executing the "view logic" in the context of the view, not the model/collection!!

```
var app = new Marionette.Application;

// your dom contains a <nav /> element in its body
app.addRegions({nav: 'nav'});

app.addInitializers( function () {

    // collection containing nav links + the 'target', i.e. an onClick handler
    var NavLinksCollection = new Backbone.Collection([
        {
            title: 'Link 1',
            onClick: function (event) {
                // your ajax request
                // this will be executed in the context of the view
                // so you will have access to the Marionette.ItemView instance, with the element attached etc
                // also, you have access to the model data, via the view's model property, i.e. `this.model`
                // also to the collection the model belongs to, via this.model.collection
                // finally, the event object is also available
            }
        },
        {
            title: 'Link 2'
        }
    ]);

    var NavView = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
            itemView: Marionette.ItemView.extend({
                template: function (model) {
                    // maybe model is already serialized, then access via model.title
                    return $('<button>' + model.get('title') + '</button>');
                },
                events: {
                    'click': function (event) {
                        // see, although the actual code of the onClick event is contained in the collection, we execute that code in the context of the view, effectively making it code 'of' the view
                        this.model.get('onClick').call(this, event);
                    }
                }
            }),
            collection: NavLinksCollections
        });

    app.nav.show(new NavView);

});

app.start();
```

Comment: I did not mean to suggest that I think view model should go into the model.  I believe it goes in the view, not hanging out in a random page function - my reference to the model was more about the fact that an action taken on a view might be an ajax function that affects the underlying model (thus even more reason it should not wired up outside the Backbone app scope).  I think, in your example, the itemView events bit is what I was after.  Thanks!